# Recursively change file name in folder and subfolders without changing file path

Tags: linux, bash, perl, ubuntu, file-rename

I have files in a format like  `639486572_016b0f3d-9ec3-4ad1-84ae-c98b68390322.wav`. The files reside in a folder and sub-folder format that resembles a date.  `./2019/05/31/639486572_016b0f3d-9ec3-4ad1-84ae-c98b68390322.wav`.

The goal is to remove everything before and including the `_`. Which im able to do with `rename -v 's/$\.+_//'`

But when I try to couple this with `find` it seems to rename all the files found in the subfolder correctly but places\moves them to the root of the folder im working out of so in this case ./2019

The command im running is `find -type f -name "*_*" |  rename -v 's/$\.+_//'`

How can I ensure the files location doesn't change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$\` will be undefined and will do nothing in your regular expression.

`.+_` will match everything from the beginning of a string to the last `_` character, including the path information. You'll want to use a more restrictive expression that won't capture the whole path.

There are a few ways you can do it:

```
s![^/]+_!!        greedy match of consecutive non-/ chars

s!(.+/)?.+_!$1!   capture path and include it in the replacement
```

There is also a solution that would use a negative look-behind assertion, when you are ready to open that can of worms.

Comment: I went `s!(.+/)?.+_!$1!`  would you recommend a site that helps better understands the expressions? Its something I definitely need to read on. Most of the stuff I found were very basic expressions.

Comment: @MurdaRalph See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Comment: @Grinnz this is perfect.